# PHP Cookie, is that wrong?

Tags: php, wordpress, cookies

I try to create a WordPress plugin, that can hold an ID in a cookie and I use the following code:

```
$cookie_value = $this->unique_id();

if ( ! isset( $_COOKIE['iwc'] ) ) {
    setcookie( 'iwc', $cookie_value, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30 );
} else {
    $cookie_value = $_COOKIE['iwc'];
}
```

but when I refresh my site, and go in my console under the Resources tab, the cookie does not appear, or can be anything wrong that I don't consider as wrong right now ?

Do you see anything wrong with this code that I don't see ?

If I `print_r` the `$_COOKIE` before the `if` statement I get the following result:

```
Array
(
    [wordpress_logged_in_87b1a17cb008ee1e12b7ec6e4e541675] => merianos|1442410181|Ddk8wElp9avfkeNXUXdcgiOnyYNNXsGLIXh8STtt0KZ|cb06a47b07c47c358799d51e7e63af1a4385badb17577f2638916c47f58cde17
    [wordpress_sec_2a5b5b648d80646a801feae602295c7a] => merianos|1442487966|3M9DcmRZifiL1e23B6iVN8vypxUTDYtZCtut75XmTJh|87e1b80dc84d4c21cebab68ea284900e53310d6d747be7db9ad756de7c7c3b73
    [wordpress_logged_in_2a5b5b648d80646a801feae602295c7a] => merianos|1442487966|3M9DcmRZifiL1e23B6iVN8vypxUTDYtZCtut75XmTJh|0a8b402565762e23c6c3cba6e34795370d25b00af393881635fba0c520f5cfc9
    [wp-settings-time-1] => 1441357608
)
```

and if I print it out after the cookie set I get this:

```
Array
(
    [wordpress_logged_in_87b1a17cb008ee1e12b7ec6e4e541675] => merianos|1442410181|Ddk8wElp9avfkeNXUXdcgiOnyYNNXsGLIXh8STtt0KZ|cb06a47b07c47c358799d51e7e63af1a4385badb17577f2638916c47f58cde17
    [wordpress_sec_2a5b5b648d80646a801feae602295c7a] => merianos|1442487966|3M9DcmRZifiL1e23B6iVN8vypxUTDYtZCtut75XmTJh|87e1b80dc84d4c21cebab68ea284900e53310d6d747be7db9ad756de7c7c3b73
    [wordpress_logged_in_2a5b5b648d80646a801feae602295c7a] => merianos|1442487966|3M9DcmRZifiL1e23B6iVN8vypxUTDYtZCtut75XmTJh|0a8b402565762e23c6c3cba6e34795370d25b00af393881635fba0c520f5cfc9
    [wp-settings-time-1] => 1441359132
)
```

In addition, I have try the following in the main file of my plugin and still doesn't work:

```
function c() {
    setcookie('iwc', 'nikos', DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30, PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), false);
}
add_action( 'init', 'c' );
```

Finally I try the following code directly in my plugin main file and still the cookie doesn't set:

```
setcookie('iwc', 'nikos', DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30, PLUGINS_COOKIE_PATH, COOKIE_DOMAIN, is_ssl(), false);
```

Comment: @RyanVincent thanks for your reply. I am sure I try to set the cookie before send anything to the browser.

Comment: ID is user or post id?

Comment: @MrD neither. It is an MD5 string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An excerpt from the [`setcookie()` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.setcookie.php):

> **expire**
>
> The time the cookie expires. This is a Unix timestamp so is in number of seconds since the epoch. In other words, you'll most likely set this with the time() function plus the number of seconds before you want it to expire. Or you might use mktime(). time()+60*60*24*30 will set the cookie to expire in 30 days. If set to 0, or omitted, the cookie will expire at the end of the session (when the browser closes).

In plain English, the argument `$expire` **is not** the life time of the cookie, as you tried to set it, but the absolute moment in time when the cookie expires.

As the documentation explains, you can/should use the result returned by [`time()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.time.php) and add the desired cookie life time (in seconds) to it.

The correct code is:

```
setcookie('iwc', $cookie_value, time() + DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30, '/');
```

Of course, you should not forget to set the correct path (`/` or another one) where you want your cookie to be used (as indicated by Mike Vranckx int [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32394532/4265352)).

**Why your code doesn't work?**

It works, but it does a different thing. You pass "30 days" on the `$expire` argument to `setcookie()` and that means "30 days after Jan 1, 1970 0:00", i.e. a date in the past. PHP generates and sends the correct `Set-Cookie` header and the browser, because of the date in the past, understands that it has to remove any cookie it has with name `iwc` for the matching path and domain.

You can see the response received from the server in the Network tab of the Developers Tool and you can see the `Set-Cookie` header is present and it has a date in the past on the `expires` field.

Comment: You are totally right !! Thanks a lot. I was already freaked out because of that issue. You are the best ;) Thanks !!!!!!

Answer (score 1):

Code looks correct, but currently you are setting a cookie for the current path, not for the global website.

You should need to set it like this, by passing `/` as path argument, if you want it to be global

```
setcookie( 'iwc', $cookie_value, DAY_IN_SECONDS * 30, '/' );
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, but still doesn't work. Also I had try this option, as well the site domain, but again no effect.

Comment: What do you have when doing a `print_r($_COOKIE);` before your `if` condition ?

Comment: Ok thanks. What is the value of `DAY_IN_SECONDS` and does actually `$cookie_value` contains a value ?

Comment: The `DAY_IN_SECONDS` is a `WordPress` constant containing the 24 hours of a day in seconds, and the `$cookie_value` it is an `md5` string.

Comment: When does your code executes? When `<html>` has already been outputted, `setcookie` will not work

Comment: Nope. I try to set the cookie on action init, that is very early inside the WordPress execution workflow. Also, when I print_r the $_COOKIE, I follow the function with die, and the only code I had in my page source code was the print_r, meaning that nothing comes in my browser at this point of time.